# Game Object Deleting Itself Prematurely

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working through the Unity tutorials, and am currently on a tutorial called "Space Shooter." Something fishy has happened.

I noticed that the Boundary object, and the asteroid object both disappear when the game begins running. Note, both have colliders, and they are not touching. Their is a script called "DestroyByContact", which essentially destroys the game object whenever the player shoots it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections; 

public class DestroyByBoundary : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
     void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
     { 
           if (other.tag == "Boundary") 
           { 
                return; 
           } 

           Destroy(other.gameObject); 
           Destroy(gameObject); 
     } 
}
```

I found that when I delete this script off of my Asteroid gameObject, the game functions normally, and the objects are deleted. Their must be something wrong with the script, but I cannot find out what went wrong.

EDIT: I forgot to place the Boundary object to the tag "Boundary" in Unity. This fixes the problem.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it and putting a break point on the first line of the function?  What did the stack trace look like?  What was the "other" thing?

Comment: Could you elaborate please?
Which objects have this script on them? And which ones have DestroyByContact on them?

Comment: Just BTW, a minor unrelated point you sometimes have to use `DestroyImmediate` if you logically need it to disappear inside the frame (perhaps because you check for it's existence later, for some logical test).

Comment: Conventional wisdom says you should really use .Equals(""); instead of == "" when doing string comparisons.

Comment: Double check tag on boundaries if it is really set to `boundary`?

Comment: Hi @ColinStricker is there a chance you could chime in on this after all the effort people have made?

Comment: @ApolloSoftware Actually for a tag check in Unity 5.x+ you really should be using [`GameObject.CompareTag(string)`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CompareTag.html)

Comment: Fair enough, though tags are just string values!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have not set or misspelled your boundary's tag `Boundary`<sup>1</sup>. See [This point in the tutorial video](https://youtu.be/OtPSvgr_ywY?t=677).

This is causing your `if (other.tag == "Boundary")` to be false so it does not go in to the `if` block to exit the function early.

**P.S.**: If you are using Unity 5 you should now use [`if (other.CompareTag("Boundary"))`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CompareTag.html), it was not in Unity 4 when the space shooter tutorial was written and it *supposedly* has better performance than doing a `other.tag == "Boundary"` compare. You can see a example of it used [in the Roll-A-Ball tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-a-ball/collecting-pick-up-objects?playlist=17141) which is written in Unity 5. The Roll-A-Ball tutorial also has a example of adding a new custom tag in the Unity 5 UI.

---

<sup>1: Ironically I misspelled `Boundary` when I first posted this answer.</sup>

Comment: Thought you misspelled it intentionally! "It's a feature, not a bug!"